# AngularJs directive not working/visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just getting started with AngularJs. And I'm trying to implement a login directive. But I don't see the output? I've no errors in my console.

My application structure:

[image]

(`index.html` is not visible)

**login.directive.js** :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('lnjapp.login',[])
        .directive('login', login);

    function login() {
        var directive = {
            template: '<p>test</p>',
            //restrict: 'E',
            Controller: LoginController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
        return directive;
    }   
})();
```

**app.js** :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('lnjapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'angular.filter','lnjapp.login','lnjapp.config'])
    .constant('GLOBALS', {
        url:'http://domain.dev/api/v1/'
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.material.init();
    });
})();
```

**app/pages/login.html**:

```
<login></login>
```

--**EDIT**--

**login.controller.js**:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('lnjapp.login',[])
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

function LoginController()
{}
})();
```

**route-config.js**:

```
angular
    .module('lnjapp.config',[])
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/pages/login.html'
        });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the `restrict` property? The angular documentation says that it defaults to element or attribute, but I swear I ran into this before.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to troubleshoot your issue.  It is possible that it could be an issue with the route to the page, which you aren't showing here; Also, directives which declare a controller will not load if the controller does not exist, so it is possible that it is a problem with the controller definition, which you also haven't listed here.

Comment: @Claies please see my edit.

Comment: @mdickin yes I've tried that.

Comment: `Controller: LoginController,` should be lowercase "controller". Not sure if that will fix everything though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **creating** your `lnjapp.login` twice, once in `login.directive.js` and again in `login.controller.js`.  The second time the module is created, it overwrites the first, and whatever was created in the first file will no longer be accessible.

You should always only create a module once, and get the already created module to add additional features in all other cases.

Set (create):  `angular.module('lnjapp.login',[])`

Get (consume): `angular.module('lnjapp.login')`

For more info and other best practices, see John Papa's excellent [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#setting-vs-getting).